# javascript FF Firebug profile() - way to get the results?

Tags: javascript, firebug

When using Firebug to profile() a function I made in javascript, the results are shown in the console area. Is there a way to get at the data returned by profile() from within javascript?

I want to do this so I can make a graph of Own Time (one of profiles results). I want to do this because the time reported by profile varies, even for trivial functions looped a few 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in Firebug but in Chrome you can look at

`console.profiles`

Firebug does not seem to have an equivelant.

Comment: There's definitely nothing listed in the [Console API reference](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API).

Comment: @AndyE there is no way to get at it in firebug but the chrome profiler lets you get at it via `console.profiles`

Comment: yes, sorry I was referring mostly to the last line of your answer.